# HTTP 500 error when uploading image in Laravel media-library

Tags: php, laravel

When I upload small files (around 2 0r 3MB), everything works. However when I try to upload a more than 3MB image, I get a http 500 error.

php.init:
upload_max_filesize = 200M;post_max_size = 220M;memory_limit = 512M

medialibrary config file:
'max_file_size' => 1024 * 1024 * 100;

i dont know what to do.Thanx in advance

Comment: Change your `APP_Debug=true` and give the error message here

Comment: its already set true :(

Comment: Check your error in `storage/logs/laravel.log`. A 500 Server Error can mean anything, but the contents of that file, referenced at the point of that error will tell you exactly what went wrong.

Comment: can you show, the error_log file if you have apache server?